# Ionic blank screen in browser but works on device

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Originally when I started this project `ionic serve` was working fine in the project before, until just recently. Now when using `ionic serve` I just get a blank white screen with only my navbar showing. But everything works fine when doing `ionic build android` and running it on mobile.

Also I don't see any console errors, or network errors at all.

Comment: Take a look at console

Comment: @Antonis I said already, there are no errors in the console.